# JAX-RS validating Content-Type and Accept header for generic upload and download API

Tags: jax-rs

The requirement is to implement a `POST /v1/data` and `GET /v1/data` API.

The upload API (`POST`) can have any `Content-Type`. This is not a problem as the content type is stored in database along with data.

The download API (`GET`) should:

1. set the same `Content-Type` as the last upload call and
2. validate with the `Content-Type` and the `Accept` headers received in the request.

The problem is in validating the `Content-Type` with the `Accept` header. The `Accept` header can be `*/*`, `text/*` (partially concrete) or `text/plain` (completely concrete). If the last uploaded `Content-Type` is `text/plain` all the three above `Accept` headers are valid.

Is there a built in method such as `bool validate(accept_header, content_type)` which does the validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a `String` to a [`MediaType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html) object with [`MediaType#valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-):

> Creates a new instance of MediaType by parsing the supplied string.

and check it with [`MediaType#isCompatible`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html#isCompatible-javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType-):

> Check if this media type is compatible with another media type. E.g. image/* is compatible with image/jpeg, image/png, etc. Media type parameters are ignored. The function is commutative.